# Issue when populating data into df

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe by macthing the values in one of its column with a second dataframe. I've used this methodology in other parts of the code, but now I can't make it work.

Some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("d","c","f","r","t","w"),b=c("A01","B02","B02","C04","A01","C02"))
df
  a   b
1 d A01
2 c B02
3 f B02
4 r C04
5 t A01
6 w C02

ECOdf <- data.frame(ECO=c("A01","B02","C04","C02"),ECO.description=c("opening1","opening2","otherOpening","lastOpening"))
ECOdf
ECO ECO.description
1 A01        opening1
2 B02        opening2
3 C04    otherOpening
4 C02     lastOpening
```

Now, I'm trying to create a new column in df filled with values from ECOdf$ECO.description by matching df$b with ECOdf$ECO. In other parts of the code I've used the following (withdifferent df and variables, I've updated the variables names to fit this example):

```
df$desc <- ECOdf$ECO[df$b]
```

and I have no errors, but the new column is filled with NA:

```
df
a   b desc
d A01 <NA>
c B02 <NA>
f B02 <NA>
r C04 <NA>
t A01 <NA>
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
df
a   b desc
d A01 opening1
c B02 opening2
f B02 opening2
r C04 otherOpening
t A01 opening1
```

Does somebody knows where's the error in the logic? I've checked both class and typeof of df$b and ECOdf$ECO and both are "character", so I have no clue on why the new column is not filled with the expected values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier using a join?

```
colnames(df)[2] = "ECO"
dplyr::left_join(df, ECOdf)
```

```
Joining, by = "ECO"
  a ECO ECO.description
1 d A01        opening1
2 c B02        opening2
3 f B02        opening2
4 r C04    otherOpening
5 t A01        opening1
6 w C02     lastOpening
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, thanks @user438383 , but still I'm quite curious why the method that I mentioned is not working

Comment: AFAIK indexing a vector using a string will always return ``NA`` - i.e. ``letters["a"]`` will return ``NA`` even though ``a`` is in the vector ``letters``.